# Ionic + Angular (mobile) keep the background still between page visits

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, background, components

I have a **shared component** (in angular) which is an animation and I want to set that as a *permanent background* across the pages. So when I browsing the app, this background would remain still and not reloading on each page. For instance imagine the swipe gesture which will change the content, but not the background - in that case, it would remain. How can I set a component like that? I would appreciate any approach!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the app.component.html is cover the task for that. Like so:

```
<ion-app>
  <app-animation></app-animation>
</ion-app>
```